# Random stats application? (console C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, console

Create a Random Stats application using C# console that asks a user to enter a number.  It should then generate that many random numbers between 0 and 9 and then displays the number of occurrences of each number. Application output should Output:

```
Enter a number: 500

Number  Occurences
0       58
1       56
2       47
3       49
4       49
5       55
6       49
7       59 
8       36 
9       42

1. Assign New Set of Integers  

2. Exit
```

Here is what I've got so far:

```
string input;
int userNumber;

Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
input = Console.ReadLine();
userNumber = int.Parse(input);

Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Number Occurrences");
int[] number = new int[10];　
int[] numberTwo = new int[userNumber];　
Random randNum = new Random();

for (int counter = 0; counter < userNumber; counter++)
 {
numberTwo[counter] = randNum.Next(10);
if (numberTwo[counter] == 0)
{
number[0]++;
}
if (numberTwo[counter] == 1) 
{
number[1]++;
}
if (numberTwo[counter] == 2)
{
number[2]++;
}
if (numberTwo[counter] == 3) 
{
number[3]++;
}
if (numberTwo[counter] == 4)
{
number[4]++;
}
if (numberTwo[counter] == 5)
{
number[5]++;
}
if (numberTwo[counter] == 6)
{
number[6]++;
}
if (numberTwo[counter] == 7)
{
number[7]++;
}
if (numberTwo[counter] == 8)  
{
number[8]++;
}
if (numberTwo[counter] == 9)
{
number[9]++;
}
}　
for (int numberThree = 0; numberThree <= 9; numberThree++)
{
Console.WriteLine(numberThree + "\t" + number[numberThree]);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

As you can see I've got the first part of my teachers question working already but I seem to be stumped when It comes to the next part where I have to add a function where the user may type 1 to get input a new number or press 2 to exit the program. (The program is in console btw)

Comment: avoid that (terrible) sequence of if: use a `Dictionary <int, int>`  to store the occurrences of a number; then for every `value` you get from `randNum.Next`, you can use:  `myDict[value] = myDict[value] +1`
start intializing the dict with something such `for var i =0; i <10; i++) myDict.Add(i, 0);`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll stick to the way my teachers are doing it for now. But in my own programs in the future I'll you're method to store numbers.

Comment: you can also stick with the array and avoid the multiple if: just use 
`number[numberTwo[counter]]++`; for every value of `numberTwo[counter]`. That's what you are doing now with your multiple if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would wrap it in a while-loop, and move your logic to a separate method.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EnterNumber();
            Console.ReadKey();

            bool doEnd = false;

            while (!doEnd)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("1.Assign New Set of Integers");
                Console.WriteLine("2.Exit");
                ConsoleKeyInfo info = Console.ReadKey();
                int val;
                if (!int.TryParse(info.KeyChar.ToString(), out val))
                {
                    // Error handling...
                }
                switch (val)
                {
                    case 1: EnterNumber();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        doEnd = true;
                        break;
                }
            }

        }

        private static void EnterNumber()
        {
            string input;
            int userNumber;

            Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            userNumber = int.Parse(input);

            Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Number Occurrences");
            int[] number = new int[10];
            int[] numberTwo = new int[userNumber];
            Random randNum = new Random();

            for (int counter = 0; counter < userNumber; counter++)
            {
                numberTwo[counter] = randNum.Next(10);
                if (numberTwo[counter] == 0)
                {
                    number[0]++;
                }
                if (numberTwo[counter] == 1)
                {
                    number[1]++;
                }
                if (numberTwo[counter] == 2)
                {
                    number[2]++;
                }
                if (numberTwo[counter] == 3)
                {
                    number[3]++;
                }
                if (numberTwo[counter] == 4)
                {
                    number[4]++;
                }
                if (numberTwo[counter] == 5)
                {
                    number[5]++;
                }
                if (numberTwo[counter] == 6)
                {
                    number[6]++;
                }
                if (numberTwo[counter] == 7)
                {
                    number[7]++;
                }
                if (numberTwo[counter] == 8)
                {
                    number[8]++;
                }
                if (numberTwo[counter] == 9)
                {
                    number[9]++;
                }
            }
            for (int numberThree = 0; numberThree <= 9; numberThree++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(numberThree + "\t" + number[numberThree]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Please note that this will be an infinite loop if the user never presses 2.
Also, be vary of **int.Parse**, since it could crash your app. Try to use **int.TryParse** instead.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx

As mentioned in the comments, you could really optimize your code by using a dictionary.

```
private static void UseDict()
{
    Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    int number;
    if (!int.TryParse(input, out number))
    {
        // Error handling here.
    }
    var userNumber = int.Parse(input);

    Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Number Occurrences");
    var dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    Random randNum = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);

    for (int counter = 0; counter < userNumber; counter++)
    {
        var generatedNumber = randNum.Next(0, 10);
        if (!dict.ContainsKey(generatedNumber))
        {
            // Create key.
            dict.Add(generatedNumber, 0);
        }
        // Increase count.
        dict[generatedNumber]++;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {

        var count = dict.ContainsKey(i) ? dict[i] : 0;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", i, count);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```